# Not able to update MongoDB database

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the below doc in DB:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6475dd3485054c30333cf52c"
  },
  "job_queue_name": "CURIE_BLR",
  "job_job_id": 1059,
  "job_jenkins_job_id": 0,
  "job_status": "ENQUEUED",
  "job_platform_name": "FUGAZI",
  "job_branch": "master",
  "job_json": "fugazi_imix_profiles",
  "job_email_id": "akshjosh@cisco.com",
  "job_profiles_to_run": "IPSEC_MCAST-imix_1400,IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_MCAST-imix_1400",
  "job_qt_mode": "prod",
  "job_baseline": "none",
  "job_no_of_trials": "1",
  "job_cycle": "1",
  "job_type": "UP",
  "job_submitted_time": {
    "$date": "2023-05-29T07:15:43.825Z"
  },
  "job_start_time": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "-62135596800000"
    }
  },
  "job_end_time": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "-62135596800000"
    }
  },
  "job_results": "NA"
}
```

I want to update the job_jenkins_job_id and job_status. Using the below code but its not updating. No error is also thrown.

I want to make sure that the update happens and I get the count of updated docs. How to achieve this?

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://10.64.127.94:27017/")
mydb = myclient["UPTeam"]
mycol = mydb["perf_sdwan_queue"]

myquery = {"$and":[
                        {"job_job_id":{"$gt":"{}".format("1059")}},
                        {"queue_name":{"$gt":"CURIE_BLR"}}
                        ]}
newvalues = { "$set": { "job_jenkins_job_id": 12, "job_status": "RUNNING" } }
mycol.update_one(myquery, newvalues)
```

myquery is not returning anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query is just wrong, so there are no matching items.

Try

```
myquery = {
    "$and": [
        {"job_job_id": 1059},
        {"queue_name": "CURIE_BLR"},
    ]
}
```

instead...